# Is there a python pandas function to directly read .data file?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, machine-learning

I'm working on a dataset and the data is provided to us in a **.data** file. is there any direct function like read_csv or read_excel?

Comment: I don't know any specified file extension `*.data`. Therefore it depends on how the file is constructed. Maybe you should give and extract of that file.

Comment: could you show how this file looks from inside?
as i know .data is tab -delimiter file so if you convert it to txt, you can open it with pandas using tab separator, with header included

Comment: It depends on what format is the .data file... More seriously `.data` is not dedicated to a well known format, so the current question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 0):

No. A `.data` file could be absolutely anything.

Use the `file` utility to try to identify the file format, or better yet ask the party you got the data from what it is.